# Store a variable out of a script

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, playframework, refresh

I'm using Play Framework and in a views .html file I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function() {
    $.get("file2", function(${list1}, ${list2}, ${list3}){
       $("#result").html(data, options);
        })
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

Which is basically a "timer" that obtains a Flot Chart plot inside the file 2 and I expect to get it in the result element. The code inside file 2 works and plots properly while handling it individually, but of course when I plot in this file I write:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                myPlot = $.plot($("#placeholder"), data, options);
            });
```

Now, what I want is to obtain in the file 1 (the one that contains the first fragment of code) the data and options placed in file 2 inside script tags, but Firebug tells me that data and options are undefined in file 1. How can I store them or what would be the best option to obtain the data used in file 2 to plot? (It is inside script tags). Thanks!

Comment: where are `data` and `options` being defined in the first place?

Comment: Inside the file in which I use them to plot using Flot Charts

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
$.get("file2", function(${list1}, ${list2}, ${list3}){
```

doesn't look right. The "success" callback function with `$.get` gets called with the following:

```
Function(PlainObject data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR)
```

and so it would make better sense for you to use something like:

```
$.get("file2", function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
  // use the data
});
```

This:

```
$("#result").html(data, options);
```

doesn't look right either.  The `.html` function with jQuery has the signature:

```
.html(htmlString)
```

or:

```
.html(function)
```

In your code, what it does is to replace the HTML with what's in `data`.  The `options` is not used at all.

If you want to store `${list1}` and so forth, you'd want to do something like:

```
var list = $list1; // curly brackets not necessary
```

then you can use it in the rest of the JavaScript code.